# How can the defense be called for 12 men pre-snap?

Tags: american-football, officiating

I saw a game last night where a penalty was called on the defense for having too many men on the field before the ball was snapped.

This was baffling to me. It's my understanding that it's not a penalty until the ball is snapped.

In what circumstances could a penalty be called on the defense for too many men on the field when the ball has yet to be snapped?